# How to draw a shape in a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

In a Python program, I have defined a 2D array called s, which is initialized with zeros. Now, I want to modify specific regions by setting all the values within an irregular polygon to 1. The vertices of this polygon are assumed to be known in terms of their positions in the s array. How can I implement this idea?

```
#variable declarations
Lx = 1.7  
Ly = 1.7  
Nx = 170
Ny = 170  
x = np.linspace(0, Lx, Nx+1)  # x方向空间网格     
y = np.linspace(0, Ly, Ny+1)  # y方向空间网格
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
#s array
s = np.zeros((Ny+1, Nx+1))  

polygon_vertices = [(10, 10), (50, 10), (50, 70), (10, 70)]
polygon_path = mpath.Path(polygon_vertices)

#change s
for i in range(Ny+1):
    for j in range(Nx+1):
        if polygon_path.contains_point((X[i, j], Y[i, j])):
            s[i, j] = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df.to_excel('s.xlsx', index=False)
```

This is the code I tried to write, but it doesn't seem to modify the array s. Please point out my mistakes and help me make the necessary corrections. Thank you!

Comment: Aren't X and Y <= 1.7, but every value in your polygon >= 10?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing to coordinate systems in your code, you have one system that is "real" (from 0 to 1.7 in both directions), and another that is "indices" (from 0 to 170). While your polygon is defined in "indices", you check if points on the "real" system are inside of it. Instead, you should do both operations on the same space, the following just uses the "indices" one:

```
#variable declarations
Lx = 1.7  # not needed
Ly = 1.7  # not needed
Nx = 170
Ny = 170  
x = np.linspace(0, Lx, Nx+1)  # x方向空间网格     
y = np.linspace(0, Ly, Ny+1)  # y方向空间网格
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  # not needed
#s array
s = np.zeros((Ny+1, Nx+1))  

polygon_vertices = [(10, 10), (50, 10), (50, 70), (10, 70)]
polygon_path = mpath.Path(polygon_vertices)

#change s
for i in range(Ny+1):
    for j in range(Nx+1):
        if polygon_path.contains_point((i, j)):
            s[i, j] = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df.to_excel('s.xlsx', index=False)
```

This way, you don't even need the Lx, Ly and X and Y variables for the shape definition (as you never use the "real" coordinate system.

Comment: thank you! your answer is helpful to me.

Answer (score -2):

I misunderstood your loop conditions. It seems there's an issue with how you are checking if a point is inside the polygon using contains_point. The contains_point function expects the input point in a specific format. It requires a single tuple as input, not separate x and y coordinates.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.path as mpath

# Variable declarations
Lx = 1.7
Ly = 1.7
Nx = 170
Ny = 170
x = np.linspace(0, Lx, Nx + 1)  # x方向空间网格
y = np.linspace(0, Ly, Ny + 1)  # y方向空间网格
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# s array
s = np.zeros((Ny + 1, Nx + 1))

polygon_vertices = [(10, 10), (50, 10), (50, 70), (10, 70)]
polygon_path = mpath.Path(polygon_vertices)

# Change s
for i in range(Ny + 1):
    for j in range(Nx + 1):
        if polygon_path.contains_point((X[i, j], Y[i, j])):
            s[i, j] = 1  # Set to 1 if inside the polygon

df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df.to_excel('s.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: The loops were consistent with the array s definition (which also used Nx+1, Ny+1 for its shape). And that was not the reason for the code not working properly